# Javascript Multiline unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting an error on the first time telling me it has an unexpected identifier.
  I am unsure what is causing it, I am making a big string of code so users can copy and paste it to use on webpages.

```
var generatedCode = " \
init(); \
<script> \
function init()  \
{ \
  disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('bitcoin')); \
  disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('litecoin')); \
  disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('peercoin')); \
  disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('namecoin')); \
} \
";
```

Heres what it looks like: http://pbrd.co/1jawPVZ

Comment: What is this? Can you elaborate about what u want to achieve?

Comment: You haven't closed the `<script>` tag.

Comment: [That code](http://jsbin.com/IkEVANu/1/) does not throw any error.

Comment: http://pbrd.co/1jawPVZ

Comment: @R00059159 - You can't have multi-line string declarations enclosed in single quotes! Your question has double-quotes (which is correct) and the pasteboard link you posted has single quotes (which is incorrect)!

Comment: Ah, I was trying different things to get it working and changed it a while back, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [screen](http://pasteboard.co/2PcbE2v8.png) shows what your are using single quotes only. For `generatedCode` use `"` and for document.getElementById calling use `'`. Or for `generatedCode` use `'` and for document.getElementById calling use `"`. For more info read [this snippet](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/quotesin.htm).

Also you need close `<script>` tag and call `init` in script tag:

```
var generatedCode = " \
<script> \
function init()  \
{ \
  disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('bitcoin')); \
  disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('litecoin')); \
  disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('peercoin')); \
  disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('namecoin')); \
} \
init(); \
</script>";
```

**OR**

remove `script` tag from your code if you call it in `eval` for example (but better do not use eval):

```
var generatedCode = " \
    function init()  \
    { \
      disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('bitcoin')); \
      disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('litecoin')); \
      disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('peercoin')); \
      disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('namecoin')); \
    } \
    init();"
```

Comment: Still nothing, im sure its <\/script> also but I dont think any of this matters since its a string it does not have to work.

Comment: I edit my answer, because your screen shows what your are using single quotes only.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `init()` function outside your `<script>` tags, try placing it between `<script>` and function `init()`

Answer (score 0):

```
var generatedCode = "\
\<script\> \
function init()  \
{ \
  disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('bitcoin'));\
  disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('litecoin'));\
  disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('peercoin'));\
  disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('namecoin'));\
} \
init(); \
\<\/script\> \
";
```

Just missing a few escapes on the brackets. Also errors within the returned string. This will work for you though.

**generatedCode value:**

```
<script> function init()  {   disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('bitcoin'));  disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('litecoin'));  disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('peercoin'));  disableDraggingFor(document.getElementById('namecoin'));} init(); </script>
```